# How do I delete a file with invalid characters in Windows 8.1 (not even Cygwin helps)

Tags: cygwin, special-characters

After a problem I've encountered with the Windows 8 Store
I had to delete a system folder.

Unfortunately, inside it there's a file with invalid characters (filename as it's displayed via `ls` or `dir`):

```
0-FileAssociation-https∺∯∯next-services.apps.microsoft.com∯search∯6.3.9600-0∯776∯en-US_en-US.en.el∯m∯US∯c∯US∯il∯en-US∯cp∯10005001∯FileAssociation∯cid∯0∯pf∯1∯pc∯0∯pt∯x64∯af∯0∯lf∯1∯s∯0∯2∯pn∯0.dat
```

Edit: In windows it appears as

```
0-FileAssociation-https???next-services.apps.microsoft.com?search?6.3.9600-0?77‌​6?en-US_en-US.en.el?m?US?c?US?il?en-US?cp?10005001?FileAssociation?cid?0?pf?1?pc?‌​0?pt?x64?af?0?lf?1?s?0?2?pn?0?pgc?-1?phrase=sec.dat
```

It's located at in a rather long path:

```
C:\Users\Kostas\AppData\Local\Packages\winstore_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\OldCache\0
```

What I have already tried without success:

- renaming it via either File Explorer *-pressing F2 doesn't work and rightclicking doesn't show the full shell extension menu (shows only the entries Open with and Send to, instead)-*
- renaming it via  elevated cmd
- deleting via File Explorer
- starting elevated cmd and trying the `del` command
- launching Cygwin as admin and trying:

  1. `rm -rf *.dat`
  2. `mv *.dat 1`
  3. `find . -type f -delete`
  4. `rm -- *`
  5. `set -- 0-FileAssociation-https*`
     `echo "${#} file(s) found"`
     (and if the above outputs "1 file(s) found", then)
     `rm -i 0-FileAssociation-https*`

All the above 5 attempts give:
`"cannot stat/remove/delete: No such file or directory"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution:

- go to task manager and kill explorer.exe
- go to File>Run new task: cmd
- navigate to the OP path
- use the del command
- then re-launch explorer.

Credit goes to user illuminÉ.